# 'Target WSGI script cannot be loaded as Python module' in error log

Tags: python, apache, apache2, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I wrote a simple hello.py as API and would like to use it through port 8081, but encountering the problem:
***Target WSGI script '/var/www/wsgi/hello.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.***
 on Ubuntu16.04, it is a fresh install. Only apache2, flask, php and mysql are installed on this machine. The Python version is as default as 2.7.12.

I have tried several solutions searched, but none of which working for me so far. It is appreciative if anyone could help

### The following is the error.log in apache:

```
[wsgi:info] [pid 28286] [client 127.0.0.1:53384] mod_wsgi (pid=28286, process='', application='test.test123|'): Loading WSGI script '/var/www/wsgi/hello.wsgi'.  
[wsgi:error] [pid 28286] [client 127.0.0.1:53384] mod_wsgi (pid=28286): Target WSGI script '/var/www/wsgi/hello.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.  
[wsgi:error] [pid 28286] [client 127.0.0.1:53384] mod_wsgi (pid=28286):   Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/wsgi/hello.wsgi'.  
[wsgi:error] [pid 28286] [client 127.0.0.1:53384] Traceback (most recent call last):  
[wsgi:error] [pid 28286] [client 127.0.0.1:53384]   File "/var/www/wsgi/hello.wsgi", line 5, in <module>  
[wsgi:error] [pid 28286] [client 127.0.0.1:53384]     from hello import app as application  
[wsgi:error] [pid 28286] [client 127.0.0.1:53384]   File "/var/www/html/hello/hello.py", line 1, in <module>  
[wsgi:error] [pid 28286] [client 127.0.0.1:53384]     from flask import Flask  
[wsgi:error] [pid 28286] [client 127.0.0.1:53384] ImportError: No module named flask
```

Most posts talking about python version, and I verified my mod_wsgi version with ldd, believing it is Python 2.7:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff93ebe000)  
libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007f270e359000)  
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f270e13c000)  
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f270dd72000)  
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f270db58000)  
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f270d954000)  
libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f270d750000)  
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f270d447000)  
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000557eb7f65000)
```

Also print sys.version and sys.path, seems to be default 2.7 as well:

```
[wsgi:error] [pid 29129] 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10)
[wsgi:error] [pid 29129] [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
[wsgi:error] [pid 29129] ['/var/www/html/hello', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

There are several posts talking about 
https://code.google.com/archive/p/modwsgi/wikis/CheckingYourInstallation.wiki 
, but I do not understand this one

BTW, on my ubuntu 16.04 there is no /etc/apache2/httpd exists, but I found one article saying /usr/sbin/apache2 is the same. For my apache2 version info:

```
/usr/sbin/apache2 -V
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2016-07-14T12:32:26
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:52
Server loaded:  APR 1.5.2, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
Compiled using: APR 1.5.2, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     prefork
 threaded:     no
   forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
-D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
-D APR_HAS_MMAP
-D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
-D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
-D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
-D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
-D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
-D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
-D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
-D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/apache2"
-D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"
-D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"
-D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
-D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
-D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="mime.types"
-D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="apache2.conf"
```

Any hints would be appreciative.

#### More Info:

My machine is behind a router, with port forwarding correctly (tested with phpInfo() page on apache2 before applying wsgi).

file structure:

```
/var/www/
--------/html/
-------------/hello/hello.py
-------------/index.html
-------------/index.php
--------/wsgi/hello.wsgi
/etc/apache2/
------------/site-available/
---------------------------/test.test123.conf
---------------------------/000-default.conf
---------------------------/default-ssl.conf
------------/site-enabled/
---------------------------/000-default.conf
---------------------------/test.test123.conf
```

hello.py:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/<sInput>')
def hello_world(sInput):
    return sInput
```

hello.wsgi:

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/html/hello')
print(sys.version)
print(sys.path)
from hello import app as application
```

test.test123.conf:

```
<virtualhost *:80>
    ServerName test.test123

    WSGIDaemonProcess hello user=www-data group=www-data threads=5 home=/var/www/html/hello/
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/wsgi/hello.wsgi

    <directory /var/www/html/hello>
        WSGIProcessGroup hello
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        WSGIScriptReloading On
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </directory>
</virtualhost>
```

/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       test123-Ubuntu16.04     test123-Ubuntu16
127.0.0.1       test.test123
```

/etc/apache2/ports.conf:

```
Listen 80
Listen 8081
```

If there is any further info need to provide, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Is Flask installed into a Python virtual environment? See http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Comment: No, not using virtual env.

Comment: From command line Python, if you for ``import flask; print(flask.__file__)`` what do you get?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton it is:
/home/<my username>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/__init__.pyc

Comment: When running mod_wsgi from Apache started as system service, it will not look in a per user Python site-packages directory. Create an independent Python virtual environment, install things in that and then tell mod_wsgi where that Python virtual environment is.